# Box A contains 10 red and 5 yellow balls while box B contains 5 red and 6 yellow balls.

Tags: probability, statistics

Box A contains 10 red and 5 yellow balls while box B contains 5 red and 6 yellow balls. A box is chosen at random and a ball is selected from it. The probability of choosing box A is 55%. Find the probability that the ball came from box B if the ball was yellow.

I'm having a hard time with these questions as this wasn't covered in our lesson. :(

Comment: Have you tried it, what was your attempt?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to plug things in. In this lesson the only formula we were given was 

P(A|B) = P(A & B)/P(B) and I don't know how to plug in the probability of which box. :c

Comment: I didn't know how to type in the intersection symbol lol

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to use Bayes' Theorem, where $$P\left(\text{box B}|\text{Yellow}\right)=\frac{P\left(\text{box B}\right)\cdot P\left(\text{Yellow}|\text{Box B}\right)}{P\left(\text{Yellow}\right)}$$
and try to calculate the probabilities on the right hand side based on the given conditions.

Comment: Thank you! I will try using this. :) I appreciate the direction.

Comment: I got the answer 0.5724
 Is this correct?

Comment: It's correct :)

Comment: Yay! Thanks for your help. ^.^

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

If we chose from box $A$, and that has $0.55$ probability, then the probability we got a yellow marble is $\frac{5}{15}$. However if we chose from box $B$, and that has $0.45$ probability, then the probability we got a yellow is $\frac{6}{11}$. Hence the probably of getting a yellow by the law of total probability is,

$$(0.55)(\frac{5}{15})+(0.45)( \frac{6}{11})$$

So the answer is,

$$\frac{(0.45)( \frac{6}{11})}{(0.55)(\frac{5}{15})+(0.45)( \frac{6}{11})}$$

By Bayes' rule.